# Using geographical coordinates in python bokeh

Tags: python, maps, coordinates, bokeh

I'm trying to use bokeh for plotting of data on a map:

```
    from bokeh.io import output_file, show
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON_RETINA

    lat = 8350000 # 
    lon = -4888000
    fig = figure(tools='pan, wheel_zoom,reset', x_range=(lon-100000,lon+100000), y_range=(lat-100000, lat+100000))
    fig.square_x(lon,lat, size = 25, fill_color = None,line_color = "green", line_width = 2)
    fig.axis.visible = True
    fig.add_tile(CARTODBPOSITRON_RETINA)
    output_file("CARTODBPOSITRON_RETINA_plot.html")
    show(fig)
```

I would like to use geographical coordinates (e.g. decimal degree) to add points to the map. How can I convert geographical coordinates to the coordinates used in bokeh? Furthermore I don't know how to change the axis to degrees.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I found a solution  [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156035/calculating-mercator-coordinates-from-lat-lon/156046): `import math
def merc(lat, lon):
    r_major = 6378137.000
    x = r_major * math.radians(lon)
    scale = x/lon
    y = 180.0/math.pi * math.log(math.tan(math.pi/4.0 + lat * (math.pi/180.0)/2.0)) * scale
    return (x, y)`

Comment: In a first test (I used coordinates from google maps) I noticed a small longitudinal offset but could not figure out why. Furthermore is there a chance to use geographical coordinates in both x and y axis?